# How to update progress bars in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I have a little problem with updating Progress Bar on the UI. Ok, so I am binding the progress bar in the xaml like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="170" Header="TestProgress" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ProgressBar Width="200"
                        Height="10"
                        Minimum="0"
                        Maximum="100"
                        Value="{Binding Path=SubObject.progressValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </ProgressBar>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

And then in background worker I am changing the `progressValue` value. Progress bar on the UI should be updated to this value (or values as ListView is a list). The `progressValue` in `SubObject` is public to get and set. Object is also accessible as other operations are working. Only updating the progress bar is not working.

Can someone tell me how to update many progress bars in the list view? Single progress bar is easy to update but many of them are simple not.

Help :) Anybody?

Comment: setting `Mode=OneWay` doen't need the `UpdateSourceTrigger` (which is used only when `Mode=TwoWay` or `OneWayToSource`). About your issue, it happens mostly when the `Path` is simply wrong or your model is implemented incorrectly (such as the `INotifyPropertyChanged` is not implemented properly).

Comment: Does the SubObject implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface? and is the progressValue property raising the PropertyChanged event? Also, be sure to check that progressValue is a public property, not a field.

Comment: So, model (Object and SubObject) is generated from EntityFramework. But the progressValue is adres by me to a SubObject partial clas and is public to get and set. And I didn't implement INotifyPropertyChange. What I do is call RaisePropertyChange on ObservableCollection white is a ItemSource of the ListView.